# Access to another page by only clicking on the link and preventing page access by entering url in browser

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, session-variables

Is it possible to redirect a user back to 1st Page if they directly try to access the 2nd Page by entering the url on the browser and not the given link on 1st Page.

I have a link which I need the user to click in order to go 2nd Page
and not going to the 2nd Page via the entering the url in the browser. So far i tried adding a Session variable but doesn't seem to work, is there a way?

html:

```
<a href="page2.php?link=page2.php" name="link">page2</a>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_GET['link'])){
$_SESSION['link'] = $_GET['link'];
header("location: page2.php");
exit;
}
```

thank you and best regards

Comment: You would want code on `page2.php` to detect if the session variable has been properly set and return the user to page 1 if it has not. There is nothing PHP can do to stop a user typing `page2.php` into the browser so the logic to keep user on page1 until criteria has been met should be on page2

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the referrer page's URL if there exists any. This can be faked, though